# Bubble pushing of nand gates

Tags: boolean-algebra

If I have the following circuit and I want to reconstruct using only NAND gates is my approach correct?
Initial:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkFPl3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA7Qex.png)</sup>

I am getting conflicting information online so I wanted to make sure I am understanding this correctly. Are my conversions correct? A clear explanation of how to go about bubble pushing would be also very helpful.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  As for bubble pushing, consider the deMorgan's symbol for the 3-input NAND4.  A NAND is a negative OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

starting with:

```
(a AND1 b) OR1 (c AND2 d) OR1 (e AND3 f)    (#'s refer to gates in your drawing)
```

substituting NOT (x NAND y) for (x AND y):

```
(NOT (a NAND b)) OR (NOT (c NAND d)) OR (NOT (e NAND f))
```

By De Morgan, (NOT x) OR (NOT y) OR (NOT z) is same as NOT (x AND y AND z)

```
NOT ((a NAND b) AND (c NAND d) AND (e NAND f))
```

substituting (x NAND y NAND z) for NOT (x AND y AND z):

```
(a NAND1 b) NAND4 (c NAND2 d) NAND4 (e NAND3 f)    (#'s refer to gates in your drawing)
```